# Proper way to invoke powershell script from another script

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have the following powershell scripts in the same folder:

```
mainFolder
 | - subFolder
 |    | - MainScript.ps1
 |    | - SubScript.ps1
```

I want to call the `SubScript.ps1` from the `MainScript.ps1` and after some trial and error I found two ways to do that. (Note that I might call the `MainScript.ps1` from a console which current working directory is not the same directory where both script are located)

First option

```
Push-Location $PSScriptRoot
./SubScript param1 param2
Pop-Location $PSScriptRoot
```

Second option

```
& "$PSScriptRoot/SubScript.ps1" param1 param2
```

Are these two options completely equal, or is one prefered over the other? Any other better way to call another script?

As detailed in the question

Comment: I would prefer the 2nd option always but your question can lead to biased answers

Comment: `& (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot SubScript.ps1) param1 param2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these two options completely equal?

No: The first approach *changes the current location*, whereas the second doesn't.

That is, the invoked script will potentially see a different location as current, changing the meaning of any relative paths it uses.

In other words:

- The `Push-Location` / `PopLocation` technique is only necessary and only advisable *if you must ensure that the script's own location, reflected in the [automatic `$PSScriptRoot` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot) is the current location.*
- Otherwise, you indeed must form full paths explicitly based on `$PSScriptRoot`; [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out that as an alternative to your use of an [expandable (interpolating) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), `"..."`, you can use the  [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) cmdlet:

  ```
  # Equivalent to:
  #   & "$PSScriptRoot/SubScript.ps1" param1 param2
  & (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot SubScript.ps1) param1 param2
  ```

If you must **change the current location**, there's a **pitfall**:

- **Changing the current location** (be it via [`Push-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location) or [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location)) **is invariably *session-global***.

  - This contrasts with `cmd.exe`'s ability to limit current-directory changes in batch files to that batch file only, using the internal `setlocal` command. In POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash the problem never arises, because shell scripts there execute in an independent *child process*.
- Therefore, unless you restore the previous location via [`Pop-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/pop-location) (or with `Set-Location` using a variable that stored the previous location), you'll end up changing the current location for the *caller* of your script too (which may be the interactive prompt).
- The problem is that your location-restoring `Pop-Location` / `Set-Location` command *may not get to execute*, such as when the user aborts your script with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> or a fatal (script-terminating) occurs.

You can guard against the latter by using the following idiom, which utilizes the `finally` block of a [`try` / `catch`/ `finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement to ensure that `Pop-Location` / `Set-Location` is *always* called:

```
# Change to this script's location (directory).
# Normally, this shouldn't fail.
Push-Location -ErrorAction Stop -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot

try {

  # Perform operations here that rely on the script's directory to be 
  # the current location.

  ./SubScript param1 param2

}
finally {

  # Ensure that the previous location is returned to,
  # even in case of a fatal error or the user having pressed Ctrl-C.
  Pop-Location

}
```

Note:

- [GitHub issue #20490](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20490) is a proposal to encapsulate the above by introducing a `-Location` parameter to the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet.