# Include PS1-Data except script Itself

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, dot-source

I have 3 scripts in the following directories:

*C:\PS*

- Caller.ps1

*C:\PS\Module*

- Connect.ps1
- Statusbar.ps1

`Caller.ps1` and `Connect.ps1` contains the following code:

```
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot.Replace("\Module","")

#### not working ####
Get-ChildItem ".\Module" | Where {$_.Name -like "*.ps1"}|Where {$_.Name -notlike $MyInvocation.MyCommand} | ForEach {
 Write-Host $_.Name
    . .\Module\$_
}
```

The problem is that `Connect.ps1` calls itself in a loop.
Normally I'd like `Caller.ps1` to call `Connect.ps1` with all other `*.ps1` scripts except `Connect.ps1`.

Does anyone have a solution for me?

Thanks.

Comment: .... looks a little confused. What is it actually what you're trying to do? BTW: The first `Where-Object` could be replaced by a `-Filter *.ps1` on the `Get-ChildItem` 

Comment: If you want to exclude the calling script itself you may try `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name` or `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source` for the `FullName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure your code as follows, by placing the following *only* in `Caller.ps1`:

```bash
$connectionScriptName = 'Connect.ps1'
Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot\Module\* -Include *.ps1 -Exclude $connectionScriptName | 
  ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Name
    . $_.FullName
  }

. "$PSScriptRoot\Module\$connectionScriptName"
```

- This *first* [dot-sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) all `.ps1` files in the `Module` subdirectory *except* `Connect.ps1` ...
- ... and *then* invokes the latter.

Note that the current [location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Locations) is *not* changed in the code above. Doing so is best *avoided* in PowerShell scripts, because it affects the *entire session*. If you do need to change it, save the previous location first and restore it in the `finally` clause of a [`try` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) afterwards.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76852856/45375) for details.

Comment: Is using the `finally` clause better than `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location`?

Comment: @lit, you need _both_: after a successful `Push-Location`, you need a `finally` clause in order to ensure that the complementary `Pop-Location` always executes, as shown in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76852856/45375).